# Issue displaying units with Quantity[] inside bar legend

Tags: legending, units

`Quantity[]` is displaying some inconsistent behaviour when used in `BarLegend[]`. Compare the following two examples:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{"test"}, 
LegendLabel -> Row[{Subscript[v, \[Infinity]], "/(", Quantity[None, "Kilometers" ("Seconds")^-1], ")"}]], Below]]
```

which produces

[image: Quantity with LineLegend]

and

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> 
{Placed[BarLegend[
LegendLabel->Row[{Subscript[v, \[Infinity]], "/(",Quantity[None, "Kilometers" ("Seconds")^-1], ")"}],
LegendMarkerSize -> Automatic], Below]}]
```

which produces

[image: Quantity with BarLegend]

Notice how the `Quantity[]` expressed in the second example is `1 km/s` instead of `km/s`, despite the argument for `Quantity[]` being `None` in both cases.

I would like to use a `BarLegend[]` without that pesky `1` appearing (essentially example one but with a `BarLegend[]` instead). Is there any workaround for this?

Note: The shown plots have nothing to do with the legend, but I needed an example plot in order to show the behaviour that the legend was getting.

Comment: A partial workaround would be to use an empty string instead of `None`, i.e., `Quantity["", "Kilometers" ("Seconds")^-1]` It's not perfect since this leaves some space instead of the `1`. However, since it is just a label, use `"(km/s)"` instead of the `Quantity`

Comment: @BobHanlon Any thought on why does `Quantity[]` does not display the same behaviour as in the first case though?

Comment: No, I do not know why the difference occurs.